# Unable to read text file when program is not started by the user

Tags: python

A simple program to read a text file then print it:

```
file=open('C:\\test_files\\data.txt', 'r')
read=str(file.read())
file.close
print(read)
input('')
```

This works fine when I run it (double clicking the program),
however when the program is started using a batch program

```
start C:\test_files\python_program.py
```

it starts then instantly closes.

Comment: The path `'data.txt'` is relative to current working directory. Use an absolute path instead or use `cd` in your batch file

Comment: I've tried this didn't seem to help, edited question

Answer (score 0):

`.py` files aren't executable, so unless you've associated the `.py` file extension with your Python interpreter, you can't call `start` on a `.py` file.

You also aren't providing a window title.

Try this command:

```
start "this is a python window" python c:\test_files\python_program.py
```